# What is the understanding of these narrations from Ibn Abbas (RA) in the Tafsir of Ibn Kathir?

Tags: tafseer, authenticity

I was reading Ibn Kathir and came across this in his tafsir of Al-Ahzab 59:

> قَالَ عَلِيُّ بْنُ أَبِي طَلْحَةَ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ: أَمَرَ اللَّهُ نِسَاءَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ إذا خرجن من بيوتهن في حَاجَةٍ أَنْ يُغَطِّينَ وُجُوهَهُنَّ مِنْ فَوْقِ رُؤُوسِهِنَّ بِالْجَلَابِيبِ، وَيُبْدِينَ عَيْنًا وَاحِدَةً.
>
> What I could understand from it:
>
> Ali ibn Abu Talha reported from Ibn Abbas: Allah commanded the women of the Muslims when the exit from their homes for some reason that they cover their faces from above their heads with their Jilbabs and only show one eye.

On the other hand, for the tafsir of An-Nur 31, he says:

> وَقَالَ الْأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ جُبَير، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ: ﴿وَلا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلا مَا ظَهَرَ مِنْهَا﴾ قَالَ: وَجْهُهَا وَكَفَّيْهَا وَالْخَاتَمُ.
>
> What I could understand from it:
>
> A'mash reported from Saeed ibn Jubair from Ibn Abbas on the words "And do not show from their adornments except what is apparent from it" He said: "Her face, and her hands, and الْخَاتَمُ."

The first quotation seems to say that the whole face should be covered except one eye, and the second seems to say the face can be shown.

My Arabic is not that strong, so am I understanding something incorrectly? If not, what is the reconciliation between these two mentioned things? Is one narration weak?

Comment: Maybe the question is about the qualification of the narrators as for Sai'd ibn Jubayr he's a well-known Meccan mufassir from among the tabi'yn. And maybe الخاتم has a different (figurative) meaning as usually used.

Comment: The authenticity of both narrations can be discussed. A relevant answer for the first one is present [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/46836/20218). It is also possible to reconcile them that the first one is specific to when leaving from their homes, while the second one is specific to when they are within their homes and guests enter upon them, as is apparent from the version of the second hadith narrated from Ali ibn Abi Talha by [Tabari](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7798/31340#p1).

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, I hope an answer can discuss which narration is more sound. And also why Ibn Kathir chose to put two seemingly opposing narrations in different places and supported both of them. As for الخاتم, I did not know what it means. What is it?

Comment: @UmH Yes, I hope an answer can discuss which of the narrations is more authentic. And also, why Ibn Kathir chose to put and support the seemingly opposed narrations. I guess half of an answer to the question is present in the link you give.